# gcc on Mac OS X: how to link libraries installed with MacPorts?

Tags: macos, gcc, linker, g++, macports

I have installed gcc 4.6 using macports. The prefix is `/opt/local`, and I get the expected include path:

```
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:  
/opt/local/include/gcc46/c++/  
/opt/local/include/gcc46/c++//x86_64-apple-darwin10  
/opt/local/include/gcc46/c++//backward  
/opt/local/lib/gcc46/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin10/4.6.1/include  
/opt/local/include  
/opt/local/lib/gcc46/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin10/4.6.1/include-fixed  
/usr/include  
/System/Library/Frameworks  
/Library/Frameworks End of search list.
```

However, `/opt/local/lib` doesn't seem to be in the library search path, so I have to specify it with `-L/opt/local/lib` when using g++ on command line:

```
Library search paths:
    /opt/local/lib/gcc46/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin10/4.6.1
    /opt/local/lib/gcc46
    /usr/lib
    /usr/local/lib
Framework search paths:
    /Library/Frameworks/
    /System/Library/Frameworks/
```

This is a problem for other libraries installed with macports. Is there an easy way to add `/opt/local/lib` to the library search path? I have tried setting `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to no avail. I am using Mac OS X 10.6.8.

Comment: `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` is for dynamic loading at run time, not compile time.

Answer (score 7):

in your ~/.profile add the following line:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/local/lib"
```

and run `source ~/.profile` in the terminal to reload your profile.

In this way, the -L switch will be detected from gcc/g++ and used automaticaly.

Comment: How are you building? If I just use command line g++, this environment variable has no effect.

Comment: the LIBRARY_PATH variable should be used, without "-L"

Answer (score 4):

It depends if you want to link your executable dynamic or static against a library. Under OS X you add the libraries as source/object files like this:

```
 Dynamic: g++ -Wall -o myexecutable myfile.cpp /path/to/library.dylib
 Static: g++ -Wall -o myexecutable myfile.cpp /path/to/library.a
```

The best way is to use a build system, for example CMake (which can be installed from macports). And makes it very easy to find libraries, create libraries in a crossplatform way.

Comment: My question is more about how to set `/opt/local/lib` in gcc's library search path. Gcc is build in /opt/local so I'd expect it to be int he search path but it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

I found the easiest way is to set `C_INCLUDE_PATH` and `LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/opt/local/include
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/opt/local/include
export LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib
```

Comment: Thanks! That's the only solution that worked.